# what version of Apache comes with WebLogic 9.2

Tags: apache, weblogic, weblogic9.x

what version of Apache comes with WebLogic 9.2 (WebLogic Server 9.2 Maintenance Pack 4 (9.2.4.0))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Weblogic has built-in HTTP server capabilities - but this is NOT an Apache server.

So the answer to the question as you've asked is "Weblogic does not come with any Apache server built-in"

If you're looking to front a Weblogic 9.2 instance with an Apache server - then the compatible versions of Apache with WL 9.2 are [listed here](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E13196_01/platform/suppconfigs/configs92/92_over/add-ons.html)